# Why is my setter called twice?

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs, unmarshalling

I am working on a REST web service, using JAX-RS, JPA and JAXB, for the management of games and their highscores. A game has the following properties: `name`, `url` and `highscoreTableSize`.

A short description of what I'm trying to do: I have the `createRow()` method in the controller which consumes JSON (the JSON serialization of a `Game` object, class `Game` being annotated with `@XmlRootElement`), which calls the static `createRow()` from the `Game` model class, and inside of it the `setUrl()` is called. The thing is that, for some reason, the setter is called **twice**.

Now what it happens is that, if the url sent in the body of the request is not valid against a pattern, after the "mysterious" first call it becomes `null`, and the second time the setter is called, it goes inside `if (url == null)`, instead of going inside `if (!matcher.matches())`, when actually the latter is the real situation, because I've sent a mistyped URL.

Does anybody know why this is happening and how can I solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Class Game:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="games")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Game")
public class Game implements Serializable {

    //properties

    public void setUrl(String url) throws CustomWebServiceException {
        String regex = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        if ( url == null || url.length() == 0) {
          throw new CustomWebServiceException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST, new ErrorMessage("The url of the game is mandatory!"));
        } else {
          Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
          if (!matcher.matches()) { 
            throw new CustomWebServiceException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST, new         ErrorMessage("The url is invalid! Please check its syntax!"));
          } else {
            this.url = url;
          }
        }
    }

    public static Response createRow(EntityManager em, UserTransaction ut, String name, Game gameData) throws Exception {

        ut.begin();

        Game _game = em.find(Game.class, name);

        if (_game != null) {
          Util.tryRollback(ut);
          ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(
              "The game with name " + name
              + " already exists in the database!");
          throw new CustomWebServiceException(Response.Status.CONFLICT,
              errorMessage);
        }

        String url = gameData.getUrl();
        Integer highscoreTableSize = gameData.getHighscoreTableSize();

        Game newGame = new Game();
        newGame.setName(name);
        newGame.setUrl(url);
        newGame.setHighscoreTableSize(highscoreTableSize);

        em.persist(newGame);

        // force the persistence manager to save data to DB
        ut.commit();

        if (highscoreTableSize == null) {
           highscoreTableSize = 7;
        }

        SuccessfulRequestMessage succesfulRequestMessage = new SuccessfulRequestMessage(
            " Game entry created with name: " + name
            + ", url: " + url + " and highscoreTableSize: " + highscoreTableSize
            + ".");
        return Response.status(Status.CREATED).entity(succesfulRequestMessage).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{name}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createRow(
  @PathParam("name") String name, 
  Game gameData) throws CustomWebServiceException {

    try {
      return Game.createRow(em, ut, name, gameData);
    } catch (SystemException | NotSupportedException | IllegalStateException | SecurityException | HeuristicMixedException
        | HeuristicRollbackException | RollbackException e) {
      Util.tryRollback(ut);
      ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(
          "Error when trying to create entry:" + e.toString()
          + " with message: " + e.getMessage());
      throw new CustomWebServiceException(
      Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, errorMessage);
    } catch (CustomWebServiceException e) {
       throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Util.tryRollback(ut);
      ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(
          "During creation of game data, the following error(s) was(were) encountered: "
              + e.toString());
      throw new CustomWebServiceException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST,
          errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should be called twice as per your code. Once during deserialization and once you do it yourself:

```
newGame.setUrl(url);
```

Using the same class for model and for representation is a bad idea in general.
IMHO,What you should do:

- Separate your "JSON" game from the object you save in the database
- Don't do validation in your setters. There is a [Spring Validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) for that. Use that to make sure that your JSON object is valid and then just go directly for the database.
- You can use dozer to automatically convert model object to representation objects and vice versa

**Edit:**
Without using any libraries the easiest thing you can do is to move validation to a method in your controller:

```
void validateInput(Game game) throws Exception {
  if (game == null) {
   throw new Exception("Game object is not present in the request");
  }
  if (game.getUrl() == null || !game.maches({some-fancyreg-exp}) {
   throw new Exception("Game URL is not valid");
  }
  //etc, check the rest of the fields
}
```

Call validateInput(game) in your controller. After that you can be sure that the input is valid. Quick and dirty. Let setters be setters.

Comment: and what would you suggest?

Comment: Using Spring or Dozer is not really an option. This web service has educational purpose and Spring and Dozer have not been studied.

Comment: and when does JAXB call my setter the first time? does it do it when creating the `Game gamaData` parameter?

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru yup. Response gets parsed and the result is populated in a new Game object. This is when setters are called.

Comment: huh? what response? I guess you referred to the JSON string from the request body, didn't you?

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru yup, request body, sorry

Comment: but if we want to keep the validations in the model, can you think of other solutions?

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru no, you need to keep your beans as clean as possible. That also means that you need to move `createRow` from Game to the controller, or, even better, to a dedicated service.